# Resize Google chart image to fit in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, resize

Please open this link in any Web Browser and in iPhone (Simulator will do)

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=600x225&cht=p&chtt=Consumption+by+Appliances&chdl=Other+$4.62|Pool%20Pump+$6.51|Refrigerator+$1.51|Clothes%20Dryer+$1.50|Always%20On+$7.12&chl=Other+21%|Pool%20Pump+30%|Refrigerator+7%|Clothes%20Dryer+7%|Always%20On+33%&chd=t:4.62252,6.51,1.5072,1.50252,7.1232&chds=0,7.1232

The width of the image is way to big to fit in iPhone (600 px). However I want to resize it 
to fit in iPhone screen. I tried the following resizing code but no success.

```
CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
CGSize size = area.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[oldImage drawInRect:area];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I know that instead of 600 px if write 320 px it will fit in the screen but my problem is I am getting the image from a web server which uses google charts to generate chart(as PNG image) and I will receive the google chart image url from my web server which I cannot adjust.

I am storing the received URL image in UIImage using following code

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

So is there any way to reszie the received image so that it can fit completely in the screen

Note: I don't want scrolling to be done to view image. I want to fit it completely at once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you change the Size in the URL itself

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x200&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello|World

Give whatever resolution which fits you.

Comment: I am aware of that but as I am geeting the Image from web server I can't modify the URL. Anyways, I am storing the image in UImage but the size is too big to display completely on iPhone screen. So I want to resize it. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is 'how can I change what I get from the server' I don't think this is an iOS question. And @HaveyouMetPrabu's answer looks great to me.

If your question is 'what's the best way to resize this image on the iOS device' then I'd say [Image I/O](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html).

A word of caution, the code;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

blocks while the data is being downloaded. Which sitting in your office on a fast Wifi will be no problem, but out in the field will lead to your app begin killed by the watchdog.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Much appreciated. Could you please suggest any good solution to resize a large image to fit on iPhone screen completely without scrolling

Comment: If you open the URl in web browser on PC you will see complete image  https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=600x225&cht=p&chtt=Consumption+by+Appliances&chdl=Other+$4.62|Pool%20Pump+$6.51|Refrigerator+$1.51|Clothes%20Dryer+$1.50|Always%20On+$7.12&chl=Other+21%|Pool%20Pump+30%|Refrigerator+7%|Clothes%20Dryer+7%|Always%20On+33%&chd=t:4.62252,6.51,1.5072,1.50252,7.1232&chds=0,7.1232  But if you change the 600 px to 320 px some part of image is lost so there is no point in changing URL. Any suggestions please.

Comment: did you read the Image I/O docs I linked to? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-SW3

Comment: also this URL gets your image in the smaller size, just as @HaveYouMetPrabu suggested - https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x115&cht=p&chtt=Consumption+by+Appliances&chdl=Other+$4.62|Pool%20Pump+$6.51|Refrigerator+$1.51|Clothes%20Dryer+$1.50|Always%20On+$7.12&chl=Other+21%|Pool%20Pump+30%|Refrigerator+7%|Clothes%20Dryer+7%|Always%20On+33%&chd=t:4.62252,6.51,1.5072,1.50252,7.1232&chds=0,7.1232

Comment: Thanks Bill for the reply. But if I load the suggested image URL some portion of the image is missing if you see closely. For eg the word Dryer, Pump are half out of the screen

Comment: last response, as you seem to not be listening... If you want to download the large version of the image, go for it. Once you do, resize it to your hearts content with Image I/O. Read the documentation to learn, then write some code.